# Why does Kafka Streams enforce logging disabled for GlobalKTable state stores?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Why must a global table not have logging enabled in kafka?

code:

```
if (loggingEnabled) {
    throw new TopologyException("StateStore " + storeName + " for global table must not have logging enabled.");
}
```

When I am restarting my kafka application all the datastore in globalstore is getting clean. How could I can made it tolerance.

Answer (score 4):

`GlobalKTable`s use their input topic to guarantee fault-tolerance. Thus, I am not sure what you mean by

> When I am restarting my kafka application all the datastore in globalstore is getting clean.

As long as the input topic is correctly configured with log-compaction enabled, the `GlobalKTable` state will be recreated on startup even if you delete the state locally.

Enabling logging does not make sense because each `KafkaStreams` instance loads the whole `GlobalKTable` data (ie, the data is broadcasted to all instances). Changelog topics are designed for *shareded* state though using one topic-partition per shard. Thus, both concepts don't align but contradict each other.

Comment: Thanks ,i was doing stream.cleanUp() on restarting application that why my state is getting clean up on restart . so in short there will no change log topic for global store  and each instance create local store on startup every time.

Comment: Exactly. However, it's not recommended to call `cleanUp()` every time. If you don't call it, the global store does not need to be recreated and startup will be faster.

Comment: suppose I am doing some custom processing while store my data in Globalstore after taking data from the topic i.e I am creating custom key from value of message .will it restore Globalstore again in same way after deletion of state locally.

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020780/restore-global-store-from-the-topic-in-custom-manner