# How to restore global store from topic in custom manner?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

suppose I am doing some custom processing while storing my data in Globalstore after taking data from the topic i.e I am creating custom key from value of message .will it restore Globalstore again in same way after deletion of state locally.

```
override def process(key: String, value: String): Unit = {
logger.info("telephonyUsersProcessorCounter = "+telephonyUsersProcessorCounter)
telephonyUsersProcessorCounter  = telephonyUsersProcessorCounter +1
val telKey = processKey(key)
if (telKey.isDefined) {
  val telValue = processValue(value)

  if(telValue.isDefined ){

    StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(telKey.get,telValue.get)
    val compositeKeyForNumber = telValue.get.enterpriseId + telValue.get.phoneNumber
    val compositeKeyForDeviceName =  telValue.get.enterpriseId +telValue.get.deviceName
    val compositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName =  telValue.get.enterpriseId +telValue.get.phoneNumber+telValue.get.deviceName
    val telCompositeKeyForNumber =  StreamConstants.teleStore.get.get(compositeKeyForNumber)
    val telCompositeKeyForDeviceName =  StreamConstants.teleStore.get.get(compositeKeyForDeviceName)
    val telCompositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName =  StreamConstants.teleStore.get.get(compositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName)

    if(null !=telCompositeKeyForNumber ){
      if(telCompositeKeyForNumber.dateCreated.toLong < telValue.get.dateCreated.toLong){
        StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(compositeKeyForNumber,telValue.get)
      }
    }else {
      StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(compositeKeyForNumber,telValue.get)
    }

    if(null != telCompositeKeyForDeviceName){
      if(telCompositeKeyForDeviceName.dateCreated.toLong < telValue.get.dateCreated.toLong){
        StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(compositeKeyForDeviceName,telValue.get)
      }
    }else {
      StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(compositeKeyForDeviceName,telValue.get)
    }

    if(null != telCompositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName){
      if(telCompositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName.dateCreated.toLong < telValue.get.dateCreated.toLong){
        StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(compositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName,telValue.get)
      }
    }else {
      StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(compositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName,telValue.get)
    }
    context.forward(telKey.get, telValue.get.toJson.toString())
    context.forward(compositeKeyForNumber, telValue.get.toJson.toString())
    context.forward(compositeKeyForDeviceName, telValue.get.toJson.toString())
    context.forward(compositeKeyForNumberAndDeviceName, telValue.get.toJson.toString())

  }else {

    StreamConstants.teleStore.get.put(telKey.get,null)
    context.forward(telKey.get,null)
  }

}
```

}

creating custom key using data from the value of message instead of using direct key from the topic. Suppose I have delete my local Global store . What will happened while restoring this store from compact topic ?

Comment: I'm curious where you use a global state store to do _"some custom processing while storing my data in Globalstore after taking data from the topic"_? Where are you storing the data in a global store? It's not in the snippet, is it?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski :- I have updated the right code now . You can see I am creating custom key while storing in Global store from the value.

Answer (score 1):

On restore, data from the changelog topics is put into the global store as-is, skipping any custom processor logic. This is a know issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4963

Comment: Thanks,I am thinking a work around on it by creating new topic which take values of custom logic and using that compact topic I will create GlobalStore instead of creating from main topic. I could use a stream application to send the data on custom topic . is it good Idea?

Comment: That might work. If you _first_ start the application and afterward write date into the "global topic" the custom processor will be used.