# How does a global state store differ from a normal state store in kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How does a global State Store differ from a normal state store ?

Has a global state store a copy of the data in all the instances running on different machines ?
How does it behave in case of a restart ? Because a global state store doesn't use any change-log topic for restoration, in my scenario, the source topic from the global store has no key.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Change it now looks simple question with sufficient details

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between GlobalKTable and a Streams state store (using RocksDB)?

Comment: i want to know how global-state store work is it internally create any change-log topic for restore when machine restart. because in my scenario the source topic for global-state store has no key [key is null] so when i restart my machine. global state store directly load data from source topic

Comment: Please read the tag description of `confluent-kafka` before using it. It's unrelated to Kafka Streams

Answer (score 1):

1. Is Global state store has copy of data in all the instance running on different machine?

   Yes.
2. How it behave in case of restart because global state store doesn't use any change-log topic for restore in my scenario the source topic from the global store has no key:

   - `GlobalKTable` disable logging by default so it'll not push changelog to the changelog topic for `GlobalKTable` (it still creates the changelog topic though). You have to re-populate data to `GlobalKTable` from an input topic which enables log compaction (cleanup.policy=compact) which message's key is the key you want to lookup in your `GlobalKTable`. Kafka Stream will just re-populate data from the input topic to `GlobalKTable` when you restart application.
   - in my scenario the source topic from the global store has no key: you have to map your source topic to the new topic which I mentioned above using a KeyValueMapper, and enable log compaction on the output topic.

Comment: global state store don't create any change-log topic for restoration?
or only solution is re-partitioning of data to another topic that topic will be the source topic for global state store

Comment: global state use input topic instead of changelog topic for restoration, but they does create the changelog topic, it's not clearly state in the document https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#globalktable

Comment: after read your question, I run a simple topology to check and really surprise about it. You can read more in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707748/why-does-kafka-streams-enforce-logging-disabled-for-globalktable-state-stores

Comment: "only solution is re-partitioning of data to another topic that topic will be the source topic for global state store" exactly, and this topic must enable log compaction

Comment: can we enable logging on global-state-store? if we do so will it work?
i seen many workaround to create on more topic where we dump data from the source topic with our custom key which will be use by the global-state store during restore. 

but in my scenario its little bit difficult.

Comment: No, you can enable logging in `Topology.addGlobalStore()` for later used in `Processor` but it will throw a `TopologyException("StateStore " + storeName + " for global table must not have logging enabled.");`
How is that difficult?

Comment: {
      "id": "user-12345",
      "user_client": [
        "clientid-1",
  "clientid-2"
      ]
}

This is my data from input topic with key as null.

i want to create two global store one to store id -- to above record.
another one is clientid-1:["user-12345"] list.

so if you see above example. i need to store record in this way id --> whole record.
another is each client i need to maintain array list to user id example:

"clientid-1":["user-12345"]
"clientid-2":["user-12345"]

Comment: You should ask another question. But my 2 cents is : you send these to 2 different topic and use 2 separate GlobalKTable (one topic also work if you have a common serializer), but to extract `clientid-1` as key you have to used another KTable to store the aggregated result so far for `clientid` key e.g `"clientid-1":["user-12345", "user-12346", "user-12347"] `

Comment: The answer here also have an interesting approach as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029964/kafka-streams-use-cases-for-add-global-store?rq=1

Comment: continue to use the input topic and deserialize and invoke the processors during restoration as well,

how we can do this because in restore global-store bypass the processor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613596/global-state-store-dont-create-change-log-topic-what-is-the-workaround-if-input

Comment: @MohitSingh will a client_id have multiple user_id or just one?

Comment: client_id can have multiple user. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613596/global-state-store-dont-create-change-log-topic-what-is-the-workaround-if-input  created new question for this