# Does GlobalKTable maintain data after application restart?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm working with Spring Cloud Streams and I have a BiFunction that receives a KStream and a GlobalKTable. I dont want to lose the GlobalKTable data after my application restarts, but it's what is happening.

```
@Bean
public BiFunction<KStream<String, MyClass1>, GlobalKTable<String, MyClass2>, KStream<String, MyClass3>> process() { 
...
}
```

I've also configured the "materializedAs" property:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-1.consumer.materializedAs: MYTABLE
```

I Have a topic A that have a retention time of 1 week. So, if a message from topic A was erased due retention time and my application restarts, the GlobalKTable doesn't find this message.

The GlobalKTable data should really be erased when my application restarts?

Answer (score 1):

`GlobalKTable` always restores from the input topic directly. It builds the state store based on the input topic. If the state store is already there and in sync with the input topic, I believe the restore on startup will be faster (therefore, if you are using Spring for Apache Kafka < 2.7, you need to do what Gary suggested above). However, if the input topic is completely removed, then the state store needs to be rebuilt entirely from scratch with the new input topic. That is the reason, why you are not seeing any data restored on startup after deleting the topic. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707748/why-does-kafka-streams-enforce-logging-disabled-for-globalktable-state-stores) has some more details on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

See [the binder documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_state_cleanup).

> By default, the `Kafkastreams.cleanup()` method is called when the binding is stopped. See the Spring Kafka documentation. To modify this behavior simply add a single `CleanupConfig` `@Bean` (configured to clean up on start, stop, or neither) to the application context; the bean will be detected and wired into the factory bean.

Spring for Apache Kafka 2.7 and later does not remove the state by default any longer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/eff205404389b563849fdd4dceb52b23aeb38f20

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to add this CleanupConfig Bean (false,false) but it did not work. I've also tried to change the spring-kafka version to 2.7.0, but it did not work too. When I drop one of the five instances of the same application, this instance lose the GlobalKTable data.